# Receiving a Windows Security dialog when querying ODATA endpoint through an IFrame

Tags: javascript, odata, dynamics-crm-2011

I am using an IFD CRM2011 environment and I am following [this MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg985387.aspx) to query the ODATA endpoint to populate a dropdown menu within an IFrame.

Here is the  code that populates the drop down list:

```js
function GetQuestionSetList() {
    var query = '/Mhc_questionsetverSet?' +
      '$select=Mhc_name,Mhc_questionsetverId&$filter=statecode/Value eq 0';
    SDK.RestEndpointPaging
       .RetrieveRecords(query, ProcessReturnedQuestionSetVersions);
}

function ProcessReturnedQuestionSetVersions(retrievedQuestionSets) {
    for (var i = 0; i < retrievedQuestionSets.length; i++) {
        var questionSet = retrievedQuestionSets[i];
        var value = questionSet.Mhc_questionsetverId;
        var name = questionSet.Mhc_name;

        //add option to select list
        $('#selectQuestionSetVersion').append($('<option>')
                                      .attr('value', value)
                                      .text(name));
    }
}
```

After the `SDK.RestEndpointPaging.RetrieveRecords(query, ProcessReturnedQuestionSetVersions);` line executes I am prompted with this dialog:

[image]

At this point I can either enter my credentials or press cancel and the dropdown is populated.  In the developer tools I notice this error in both cases:

> SCRIPT5022: Exception thrown and not caught
>
> mhc_json2.js, line 484 character 13

```js
// If the text is not JSON parseable, then a SyntaxError is thrown.

            throw new SyntaxError('JSON.parse');  //line 484
        };
    }
}());
```

I can’t figure out why this dialog is appearing or why this error is being thrown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After posting this, I just happened to check fiddler and discovered the problem.  There are two calls to `RetrieveRecords` in my situation.  The first call returns status 200 (success) but the second returns 401.

Here are the two calls:

> **https://alpha.ftg.com:5556//xrmservices/2011/organizationdata.svc/Mhc_questionsetverSet?$select=Mhc_name,Mhc_questionsetverId&$filter=statecode/Value eq 0**
>
> **https://alpha.ftg.com:5556//xrmservices/2011/organizationdata.svchttps://alpha.ftg.com:5556/xrmservices/2011/organizationdata.svc/Mhc_questionsetverSet?$filter=statecode/Value%20eq%200&$select=Mhc_name,Mhc_questionsetverId&$skiptoken=1,'mhc_questionsetverid','%7B3F737386-54DF-DE11-A55C-00155D020C0D%7D','%7B7AF1B564-C3BF-DD11-8209-000BCDC54FC9%7D'**

In the second call the server + odata endpoint are concatenated twice.  The `RetrieveRecordsCallback` function is supposed to strip the server and endpoint url if the `__next` parameter is found as seen here:

> **MSDN explanation:**
>
> If a __next property is found the new URL with a $skiptoken is passed back to SDK.RestEndpointPaging.RetrieveRecords as the new filter parameter value so that the process is repeated for each set of records until the total >number of requested records is retrieved and the __next property is no longer returned.

```
if (null != retrievedRecords.__next) {
    // The existance of the '__next' property 
    //indicates that more records are available
    // So the originating function is called again 
    //using the filter value returned
    var filter = retrievedRecords.__next
        .replace(SDK.RestEndpointPaging.GetODataPath(), "");
   SDK.RestEndpointPaging.RetrieveRecords(filter, callback);
}
```

The `SDK.RestEndpointPaging.GetODataPath()` is appending an extra `/` between the server and endpoint parts of the url, but when the new filter parameter is returned that extra `/` has been stripped so the `.replace` function fails to replace the path and it gets appended a second time.

The fix was trivial.  Just change the `SDK.RestEndpointPaging.GetODataPath()` function to this:

```
 GetODataPath: function () {
        /// <summary>
        /// Utility function to retrieve the path to the REST endpoint.
        /// </summary>
        var serverUrl = Xrm.Page.context.getServerUrl();

        //remove the extra '/' char if it exists
        if (serverUrl.match(/\/$/)) {
            serverUrl = serverUrl.substring(0, serverUrl.length - 1);
        }

        return serverUrl + "/xrmservices/2011/organizationdata.svc";
    },
```